# Saving multiple data sets and deleting using Shiny action buttons

Tags: r, shiny

Having trouble linking two different action buttons to a rendered table. Anytime the "save cohort" action button is enabled by the user, a data set gets properly saved, and the output table "cohort_names" updates just fine. But, when I "reset cohorts", the "saved cohort" names table does not empty. In the example code below, I am referencing that same fake data set.

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {       
          populations = reactiveValues(a = 0)
          values = reactiveValues(extracted_data = NULL) 

          #This finds a dataframe to be saved
          observeEvent(input$run_query, {
            values$extracted_data = data.frame(id = c(153, 343, 996), sex = c(2,1,1)) #Just an example. Behind the scenes I am running an SQL query
          })

          #This action button saves a data frame to a reactive list
          observeEvent(input$save_cohort, {
            if(!is.null(values$extracted_data) & input$name_cohort != "a") {
              populations$a = populations$a + 1
              cname = ifelse(input$name_cohort == "", paste("Population", populations$a), input$name_cohort)
              populations[[cname]] = values$extracted_data #This object comes from a "run query" action and works just fine
              print(populations$a)
            }
          })

          #This action button is suppose to reset the reactive object "populations" to NULL and resets the counter (a)
          observeEvent(input$reset_cohorts, {
            populations = NULL
            populations$a = 0
            print(populations$a)
          })

          #Population info
          output$populations = renderText(populations$a)
          updated_names <- reactive({
              tmpnames = cbind(names(populations)[-which(names(populations) == "a")])
              colnames(tmpnames) = "Populations"
              print(tmpnames)
              tmpnames
          })

          #This is what is NOT updating. I need cohort_names to reset to nothing when reset_cohorts is enabled. It updates JUST FINE when save_cohorts is enabled. 
          output$cohort_names = renderTable({updated_names()}, align = 'c', width = "100%")
}
```

Here is a simple ui.r in case anyone wants to recreate:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(tableOutput("cohort_names")),
    mainPanel(actionButton("run_query", "Run Query"),
              actionButton("save_cohort", "Save Cohort"),
              actionButton("reset_cohorts", "Reset Cohorts"), 
              textInputRow("name_cohort",label= NULL, placeholder = "Enter Cohort Name"))
  )
)
```

My current running theory is that I am treating reactiveValues incorrectly, but I cannot for the life of me figure out an appropriate solution. Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you provide `head` of all the data required to reproduce your example?

Comment: I cannot. It's sensitive data, but the only thing you really need is a straight up data frame. Setting values$extracted_data to be something like `data.frame(id=c(142,453,273), sex=c(1,2,2))` should suffice. I'll add some more detail and it will hopefully be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I can achieve what you want, my code has a bug. If you press reset cohorts button first time, it does reset everything in the background (see console prints) but the UI does not show updated value. The second click onward on the reset cohort button, everything works as intended. Could not figure out why this is happening though :(

Here is the code in case you can live with that bug.

```
library(shiny)
server <- function(input, output, session) {       
  populations <<- list()
  pop_counter <- reactiveValues(a = 0)
  values <- reactiveValues(extracted_data = NULL) 

  #This finds a dataframe to be saved
  observeEvent(input$run_query, {
    values$extracted_data = data.frame(id = c(153, 343, 996), sex = c(2,1,1)) #Just an example. Behind the scenes I am running an SQL query
  })

  #This action button saves a data frame to a reactive list
  observeEvent(input$save_cohort, {
    if(!is.null(values$extracted_data) & input$name_cohort != "a") {
      pop_counter$a = pop_counter$a + 1
      cname = ifelse(input$name_cohort == "", paste("Population", pop_counter$a), input$name_cohort)
      populations[[cname]] <<- values$extracted_data #This object comes from a "run query" action and works just fine
      print('inside saving cohort....')
      print(populations)
      print(class(populations))
      print(pop_counter$a)
    }
  })

  #This action button is suppose to reset the reactive object "populations" to NULL and resets the counter (a)
  observeEvent(input$reset_cohorts, {
    print('inside resetting of populations list')
    populations <<- list()
    pop_counter$a <- 0
    print(populations)
    print(pop_counter$a)
  })

  updated_names <- eventReactive(c(input$reset_cohorts, input$save_cohort),{
    print('inside updated_names() ...')
    if(length(populations) == 0) return(data.frame())

    tmpnames <- cbind(names(populations))#[-which(names(populations) == "a")]
    colnames(tmpnames) = "Populations"

    print(tmpnames)
    tmpnames
  })




  #This is what is NOT updating. I need cohort_names to reset to nothing when reset_cohorts is enabled. It updates JUST FINE when save_cohorts is enabled. 
  output$cohort_names = renderTable({updated_names()}, align = 'c', width = "100%")


  }


ui <-   shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(tableOutput("cohort_names")),
    mainPanel(actionButton("run_query", "Run Query"),
              actionButton("save_cohort", "Save Cohort"),
              actionButton("reset_cohorts", "Reset Cohorts"), 
              textInput("name_cohort",label= NULL, placeholder = "Enter Cohort Name"))
  )
)
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, even with the bug! I have also found (via printing) that things reset the way I want, but as you noted, the output does not update. Super weird!!

Comment: Either way, your code is an improvement to what I have so far, so thank you

Comment: This worked!! Thanks. I guess the key was to declare "populations" globally and not as a reactive Value.

Comment: glad it is helpful :)